# When using Moq to mock an interface, what happens to the methods?

Tags: c#, testing, moq

When using Moq to mock an interface, what happens to the methods?

Let's say I have an interace `ISomething`, which IoC maps to the class `Something`. Then in my test I do this: `var something = new Mock<ISomething>();`.

Lets say the interface contains a method:
`string method();`.

Now, if I call that method on the mocked instance, `something.method()`, will it be mapped to the class `Something`'s implementation, or will it just return void? Will Moq try to map an interface with an implementation?

Comment: You need to provide the definition to the method like `something.Setup(m => method()).Returns("Return Value");`

Comment: If only it was possible to run something like `var something = new Mock<ISomething>(); something.method()` and see yourself...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Moq* won't try to use your implemenation and it in fact *doesn't know anything about it* (even doesn't care if it exists). Instead **it generates it's own class in runtime**, which implements your interface `ISomething`. And it's implementation is what you configure it to be with `something.Setup()` methods.

If you skip configuring it, it will just return default value and do nothing else. For example,

```
var something = new Mock<ISomething>();
var result = something.Object.method(); // returns NULL

var somethingElse = new Mock<ISomething>();
somethingElse.Setup(s=>s.method()).Returns("Hello World");
var otherResult = somethingElse.Object.method(); // Returns "Hello World"
```

Setups can be quite complex, if you need that, including returning different results for different arguments, or for different calls (first time return one value, for second call - another). For more details you can check [documentation](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Please note that `something.Object` and `somethingElse.Object` are completely different implementations (classes) of `ISomething` interface. You can check that by calling:

```
var whatMySomethingIs = something.Object.GetType();
var whatMySomethingElseIs = somethingElse.Object.GetType();
```